# In Python, how to get original args to constructor of mocked object

Tags: python, mocking

In Python, with test code having access to a mock object, how do I get from it the args that the code under test passed when constructing it?

Here is a distilled example of what I'm trying to do. The TODO marks the line I don't know how to do correctly as intended.

```
from unittest import mock

# Under test:
class Foo(object):
  def __init__(self, x):
    self._x = x
  def compute():
    return hash(self._x)
def computeFoo():
  return Foo("abc").compute() + Foo("def").compute()

# Test:
class MockFoo(mock.MagicMock):
  def compute(self):
    # TODO: How to get the value x which was passed to the Foo constructor?
    if self._x == "abc":
      return 0
    return 1
if __name__ == "__main__":
  m = MockFoo()
  mock.patch(__name__ + ".Foo", return_value=m).start()
  assert computeFoo() == 1
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should apply `patch()` as decorator or context manager (with `with`) to make sure it is removed after the test. Also you should use the structure of Testcase classes as intented in unittest. That allows you to use the assertion function built-in (`self.assert...`) as well.

Comment: And to your question: if you test the constructor, you should pass in defined values, so your test knows the value. Your problem is the computeFoo function, which should not be part of testing the class since it allows only one value.

Comment: I am using those things. This is a highly distilled example, perhaps too much so. I am just interested in the question of how to get from the mock object the values that the code under test passed into the constructor.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you'd have to inspect the `mock_calls` attribute.  This gets to be a bit of a bugger though because each `Foo` instance that your code creates will create a new `call` in the `mock_calls` list and when you call `compute`, you won't really have a robust way of tracking _which_ `Foo` instance the `compute` call belongs to.  You're probably better off patching `Foo.compute` with a callable mock that has a callable `side_effect`.